# How to switch to a full screen window when [fullscreenWindow makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil] seems not to work?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have two windows in my applications: window1 and window2. window2 is created after window1 per user's action.
When window2 is in full screen mode, it will belong to a separate space by default that is different from the space of window1.
My app supports to be launched from a URL and it is a singleton.

The problem is when the app is running and the window2 is in fullscreen mode: 
Try to launch the app via URL and the window2's title is specified in the URL, in the app, though

`[window2 makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil]`

is called, window2 won't become front, instead, window1 becomes front and activated.

If window2 is not in full screen mode, there is no problem for the same scenario.(window2 will be brought to front most.)

How can i make the app switch to the fullscreen space and make window2 become front when it is in full screen mode and makeKeyAndOrderFront seems not to work as expected?

I tried

`[window2 setCollectionBehavior: NSWindowCollectionBehaviorMoveToActiveSpace]`,

the result is Not what i want.

The app did not switch to the fullscreen space, but still in window1's space. 
And on the right side of the menubar, there is no fullscreen toggle button.

Comment: Finally, i found [NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES] works in this case.

Comment: Hi yyq, [NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES] should be called before or after you invoke [window2 makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil]? Thanks.